# Is it mandatory in pytorch to add modules to ModuleList to access its parameters

Tags: python, pytorch

I read some posts about ModuleList and all of them said that adding modules to ModuleList gives access to parameters of the Neural Network but in “Training a classifier” example of **60 mins blitz** pytorch tutorial the modules are not added to any ModuleList and still the parameters could be accessed using

`optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)`

This is confusing. Please clarify how the parameters are accessible even though the modules have not been added to any ModuleList

```
class mmodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mmodel,self).__init__()
        self.lst=[]
        self.lst.append(nn.Linear(1,1))
        self.lst.append(nn.Linear(1,1))
        self.mlist = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(2,1,bias=False),nn.Linear(3,1)])
    def forward(self,x):
        for m in self.lst:
            print(type(m))
            x = m(x)
        for m in self.mlist:
            print(type(m))

mm = mmodel()
mm(X)
print(list(mm.parameters())) 

<class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'>
<class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'>
<class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'>
<class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'>
[Parameter containing:
tensor([[0.2302, 0.3712]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.3451, -0.0274,  0.3990]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3258], requires_grad=True)]
```

As evident from the above outputs the parameters of modules added in a python list are not visible in the forward method. Only the parameters of the modules added in the ModuleList are visible in the forward method

Answer (score 2):

Calling `module.parameters()` lists all [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter) of the module. Concretely, every attribute on the module that is an instance of `nn.Parameter` will be in that list. Additionally to listing all the parameters of that module, it will also list all parameters of the submodules (unless `module.parameters(recurse=False)` is used). That means it will also collect all parameters of every attribute that is an instance of `nn.Module`, which includes all subclasses.

However, if you assign an ordinary list of modules to your module, they won't be included since that is an instance of `list`, but not `nn.Module`. For convenience, [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) can be used in place of a regular Python list. `nn.ModuleList` is an instance of `nn.Module` but acts similar to a list, albeit much more restricted.

Let's take a look at an example to understand what's considered a submodule:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        # This is an nn.Module, therefore it is considered a submodule
        self.single_linear = nn.Linear(10, 20)

        # This is a list, that happens to contain nn.Modules.
        # This is not a submodule.
        self.linears = [nn.Linear(20, 10), nn.Linear(20, 30), nn.Linear(20, 40)]

        # A list with ints, clearly not a submodule either.
        self.numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3]

        # This is a module, but acts like an ordinary list
        # So it's a submodule as well.
        self.linears_module_list = nn.ModuleList(
            [nn.Linear(20, 10), nn.Linear(20, 30), nn.Linear(20, 40)]
        )
```

In this model we have assigned 4 new attributes, `single_linear`, `linears`, `numbers` and `linears_module_list`. When they are assigned, PyTorch checks whether they are instances of `nn.Module`, and if they are, they will be registered as submodules.

We can verify that (leaving out `numbers`, because that is pretty clear):

```py
model = Model()

isinstance(model.single_linear, nn.Module)  # => True

isinstance(model.linears, nn.Module)  # => False
isinstance(model.linears, list)       # => True

isinstance(model.linears_module_list, nn.Module)  # => True
isinstance(model.linears_module_list, list)       # => False
```

Only `single_linear` and `linears_module_list` are in fact submodules, as they are the only attributes that are instances of `nn.Module`. The submodules can be seen with `model._modules`, but that's an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it.

```py
# The registered modules
model._modules
# => OrderedDict([
#       ('single_linear', Linear(in_features=10, out_features=20, bias=True)),
#       ('linears_module_list', ModuleList(
#           (0): Linear(in_features=20, out_features=10, bias=True)
#           (1): Linear(in_features=20, out_features=30, bias=True)
#           (2): Linear(in_features=20, out_features=40, bias=True)
#       )
#   )])
```

Comment: Can you please give an example as I am unable to understand what you mean by this statement - "However, if you assign a list of submodules to your module"

Comment: I have clarified that in the answer and provided an example to illustrate it.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed example.  If the neural network is extended by adding the python list itself then your explanation seems good. However, if the python list is iterated and the type of each item is inspected then we will see that the type of each item in the python list would be torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear and if each linear layers in the list is added individually to the neural networking even then the parameters of these linear layers(present in the python list) are invisible.

Comment: I have added some code and print results to further explain my point